# Looking to import a header file into my child theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am using a plugin called child theme configurator.

I am looking to add the header file. How might I do this?

The end goal is to add a phone number to the header. Pretty basic...i know haha

The theme is Envisioned by elegant themes

Answer (score 0):

You can go into apearance > editor and look for the header.php file and add the phone number there.

If you have no coding experience, I DO NOT recommend this, rather get help from someone who has experience. Or post the code here and we can help.